# Changing styles during clicking

Tags: css, reactjs, button, frontend, material-ui

I have ReactJS project and I want to change colour of button during clicking. I know that it is a Ripple API but it's very incomprehensible to use it. Could someone advise me how can I do that?

I've tried to create two elements - parent and child - and changed background of child to transparent while clicking. Unfortunately I have also 'classes' object responsible for changing class if button is active and it is just not working.
My code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styles from './MydButton.style';

class MyButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isClicked: false
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ isClicked: !this.state.isClicked });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      classes,
      children,
      color,
      disabled,
      className,
      onClick,
      type,
      border,
      ...props
    } = this.props;

    const myClass = this.state.isClicked ? 'auxClass' : 'buttonDefaultRoot';


    return (
      <div className={classes.parentRoot} >
        <Button
          classes={{
            root: disabled
            ? classes.buttonDisabledRoot
            : classes.buttonRoot,
            label: disabled 
            ? classes.buttonLabelDisabled 
            : classes.buttonLabel,
          }}
          {...props}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          className={myClass}
          disabled={disabled}
          type={type === undefined ? 'button' : type}
        >
          {children}
        </Button>
      </div>
    )
  }
};

MyButton.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  disabled: PropTypes.bool,
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

MyButton.defaultProps = {
  disabled: false,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(MyButton);
```

and styles:

```
    const buttonRoot = {
      border: 0,
      height: 48,
      width: '100%',
    }


export default theme => ({
  buttonDefaultRoot: {
    ...buttonRoot,
    transition: 'all 1s ease-in-out',
    backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(to right, #F59C81, #E65DA2, #E65DA2, #B13A97, #881E8E)',
    boxShadow: '0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16)',
    backgroundSize: '300% 100%',
    marginTop: 0,
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundPosition: '100% 0%',
      transition: 'all 1s ease-in-out',
    }
  },

  parentRoot: {
       ...buttonRoot,
       backgroundColor: 'red',   
       backgroundSize: '300% 100%',
        marginTop: 36,
      }, 

      auxClass: {
        backgroundImage: 'none',
      },
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Material UI Core for ReactJS

The documentation is very good. I have updated my answer to accomodate the specific needs of this question. I have also included two general solutions for anyone who stumbles upon this question.

**Tailored Solution:**

Changes background color of button from `classes.buttonDefaultRoot` (a color defined by owner of question) to the gradient defined by the owner of this question.

First step, have a variable stored in state. You can call it whatever you want, but I'm calling bgButton. Set this to `this.props.classes.buttonDefaultRoot` like so:

```
state = {
  bgButton: this.props.classes.buttonDefaultRoot,
}
```

Next, you want to define your function that will handle the click. Again, call it what you want. I will call it `handleClick`.

```
handleClick = () => {
    const { classes } = this.props; //this grabs your css style theme
    this.setState({ bgButton: classes.parentRoot.auxClass }); //accessing styles
  };
```

A couple of things are happening here. First, I am destructuring props. So, I am creating a new `const` variable called `classes` that has the same value as `this.props.classes`. The `classes` contains a set of objects that defines your `css` styles for your buttons, margins, etc. You can access those styles just like you would if you were trying to get the value of a prop in an obj.

In this case you can access your button style by doing, `classes.buttonDefaultRoot`. That takes care of your handle click function.

Last step: render the button. In your render method you want to grab your `bgButton` from state like so:

```
render() {
  const { bgButton } = this.state;
```

Then you want to assign your `className` of your button to `bgButton` and add the `onClick` functionality like this (this follows the Material UI Core documentation):

```
<Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classNames(bgButton)} onClick={this.handleClick}>Button Name</Button>
```

Putting it all together you get this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import classNames from "classnames";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

export default theme => ({ ... }) //not going to copy all of this

class MyButton extends Component {
  state = {
    bgButton: null
  };
  handleClick = () => {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    this.setState({ bgButton: classes.parentRoot.auxClass });
  };
  render() {
    const { bgButton } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className={classNames(bgButton)}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          Custom CSS
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

MyButton.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(MyButton);
```

**General Solution**

This solution is for those who want to use the predefined colors, i.e. default, primary, secondary, inherit. This implementation does not need the PropTypes or className imports. This will change the color from the predefined blue to the predefined pink. That's it.

```
state = {
  bgButton: "primary", 
} 
handleClick = () => {
  this.setState({ bgButton: "secondary" }); 
} 

render() {
  const { bgButton } = this.state; 
  return(
   ...
   <Button
     onClick = {this.handleClick} 
     variant = "contained" //checked Material UI documentation
     color={bgButton}
    > ..etc.
```

**General Solution 2**

To accommodate your custom styles to the button, you would have to import PropTypes and classNames and take a similar approach as the tailored solution above. The only difference here will be my syntax and class name. I am closely following the documentation here so you can easily follow along and readjust where necessary.

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import classNames from "classnames";
    import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import purple from "@material-ui/core/colors/purple";

    const styles = theme => ({
      container: {
        display: "flex",
        flexWrap: "wrap"
      },
      margin: {
        margin: theme.spacing.unit
      },
      cssRoot: {
        color: theme.palette.getContrastText(purple[500]),
        backgroundColor: purple[500],
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: purple[700]
        }
      },
      bootstrapRoot: {
        boxShadow: "none",
        textTransform: "none",
        fontSize: 16,
        padding: "6px 12px",
        border: "1px solid",
        backgroundColor: "#007bff",
        borderColor: "#007bff",
        fontFamily: [
          "-apple-system",
          "BlinkMacSystemFont",
          '"Segoe UI"',
          "Roboto",
          '"Helvetica Neue"',
          "Arial",
          "sans-serif",
          '"Apple Color Emoji"',
          '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
          '"Segoe UI Symbol"'
        ].join(","),
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: "#0069d9",
          borderColor: "#0062cc"
        },
        "&:active": {
          boxShadow: "none",
          backgroundColor: "#0062cc",
          borderColor: "#005cbf"
        },
        "&:focus": {
          boxShadow: "0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,123,255,.5)"
        }
      }
    });

    class MyButton extends Component {
      state = {
        bgButton: null
      };
      handleClick = () => {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        this.setState({ bgButton: classes.cssRoot });
      };
      render() {
        const { classes } = this.props; //this gives you access to all styles defined above, so in your className prop for your HTML tags you can put classes.container, classes.margin, classes.cssRoot, or classes.bootstrapRoot in this example. 
        const { bgButton } = this.state;
        return (
          <div className={classes.container}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              className={classNames(bgButton)}
              onClick={this.handleClick}
            >
              Custom CSS
            </Button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
MyButton.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(MyButton);
```

A tip. You no longer need a constructor or to bind methods.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in the topic.
Unfortunately it's not working either. Background color is not changing while clicking.

And I believe that after render method should be props, not state, right?

render() {
  const { bgButton } = this.state;

Comment: sure did the answer help at all? Or are you still stuck?

Comment: I am still stuck.

Comment: are you getting an error? or it's just not changing the color?

Comment: sorry just saw your updated comment...give me a sec to test this on my local machine

Comment: No, I'm not getting an error, just not changing color at all.

Comment: just updated the answer. that should work the draw back is that you can't add hex or rgb. so I will look into that and update accordingly.

Comment: Still the same. I am not sure if this is because I have backgroundImage: gradient. I think I should manipulate bakroundImage not background or backgroundColor. Am I right?

Comment: you want the button to change to your buttonDefaultRoot settings correct?

Comment: I want to have 
buttonDisabledRoot - disabled 
buttonDefaultRoot - normal
auxClass - clicked

Comment: check out my updated answer and see if that helps. just lmk if you have any more questions. I'm happy to help :)

Comment: You're great! Thank you for your help!

Comment: great happy coding :)